# Having trouble with href links in angular 2 html files

Tags: angular, href

I am learning Angular 2 and i have everything on my application setup. The trouble I am having is that when i click on the Facebook social media icon on the webpage, the link does not go to facebook.com. Its the last thing on the website that i havent completed but i cannot find out how to have the href in my html to correctly go to the external webpage. My question is:

If I have a a tag like:

a href="http//:www.facebook.com" class="fa fa-twitter"

What would i have to do in the component folder(.html, .ts, .css, .spec.ts), to have the facebook link work. It's probably something simple but i can't figure it out. Can someone help me out?

Comment: That should work as is; could you give a [mcve]?

Comment: That said, using .fa-twitter for a facebook link is probably not the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

Its is being escaped for safety purposes. To not escape it you can call it like this:

```
<a [href]="fbUrl" bypassSecurityTrustUrl>Test</a>
```

in the template, and need to turn `fbUrl` to `SafeUrl`, which you can do in the component like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
  fbUrl: SafeUrl;
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer    ) {
    this.fbUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl("https://facebook.com");
  }
}
```